# I can not understand the filter get from MOSSE (Visual Object Tracking using Adaptive Correlation Filters )

Tags: video-tracking

I  run the mosse code and get the tracking filter then IDFT and display as image ：
[filter image whose center have an black point  is on the top of car.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sos6C.png)

but paper display the filter is：
[this is image display by paper author.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDgLC.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual to encounter spectrum values that range from 0 to max valuue or higher. While processing numbers such as these presents no problems for a computer, image display systems generally will not be able to reproduce faithfully such a wide range of intensity values. The net effect is that a significant degree of intensity detail can be lost in the display of a typical Fourier spectrum.